# Redirect to action in area actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controller, redirecttoaction

I have an area which has a controller with some actions .

the controller name is *home*.

the action which has the problem looks like below :

```
 public IActionResult Action1()
 {
         some code ...

        return RedirectToAction("Action2");
 }
```

---

Action2 looks like :

```
 public IActionResult Action2()
 {
         some code ...

        return View();
 }
```

the problem is that it redirects to the mentioned action but it doesn't write the area name before the controller name

url should be =>  MyArea/home/action2

but it is => home/action2

which makes an 500 error .

and my startup is :

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                         areaName: "MyArea",
                         pattern: "{area=MyArea}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
        });
```

does any have any solution ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** - Change `RedirectToAction` to

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Action2", "Home", new { area = "MyArea" });
```

**2** - Your route configuration must be like this and you must register *area* **before** *default controller*

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MyArea",// or name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default",
         pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

**3** - On the top of the controller you must add `[Area("MyArea")]` *attribute*

```cs
[Area("MyArea")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: i did it and the url changed to :Home/Action2?area=MyArea instead of MyArea/Home/Action2

Comment: @SomeOne Did you add `area` in `startup` class? please show `Configure` method and `routing`

Comment: i changed it and when i type the area name it doesn't go to its default action of default controller => 404 error

Comment: @SomeOne i updated my answer and it worked successfuly

Comment: i added [Area("MyArea")] and it works . thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @SomeOne Good luck :D